# How to load a TXT File into a JList?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jlist

I have the following Java code to read a txt file:

```
    class ReadFile {
        public static void main(String [] args) {
        File archivo = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

      try {
         archivo = new File ("C:\\archivo.txt");
         fr = new FileReader (archivo);
         br = new BufferedReader(fr);

         String line;
         while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            System.out.println(line);
      }
      catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{
         try{                    
            if( null != fr ){   
               fr.close();     
            }                  
         }catch (Exception e2){ 
            e2.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
```

But I need to load that info into a `JList`, so this `JList` would show me what words I have saved in the file.  Does anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: What is a 'listbox'?  There is no such class in the J2SE.

Comment: What UI are you using? Swing? JSP? JSF? etc

Comment: Please use the code tags when posting code.  To do that, select the code sample and click the `{}` button above the message input form.  I tidied the code above a little, but also in future use a logical and consistent indent for code sections.

Comment: I believe in Java it's called a JList (Check it out here [link]http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AnexampleofJListwithaDefaultListModel.htm). Thanks Andrew for that! :)

Comment: Ah, it's Swing? You should mention and tag as such. I've edited the question.

Comment: Sorry BalusC. Yes, it's Swing. I'm just a Java Novice. ^^"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Source

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Vector;

class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        File archivo = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            archivo = new File ("ReadFile.java");
            fr = new FileReader (archivo);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            // normally I would prefer to use an ArrayList, but JList
            // has a constructor that takes a Vector directly.
            Vector<String> lines = new Vector<String>();

            String line;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                lines.add(line);
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(new JList(lines)));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try{
                if( null != fr ) {
                    fr.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Screen shot

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrew! You rock! I was looking for that and I couldn't figure it out. Do you know if there's some way so that if I have in my TXT file some kind of format... Like for example:
Name: John - Age: 28
Name: Rose - Age: 25
It'd be difficult to load the data, like:
John
28
Rose
25
?

Comment: @mandy: It actually sounds as though this data might be better presented in a `JTable`.  As to getting the data in the form needed for a table model, I'd need to know further details of the exact format of the file.  Can you edit your question and post an example file?  Can we expect all names are a single `String`?  E.G. there are no John Smith's or Rose Van Der Ven's?

Comment: Vector class is obsolete, you should use ArrayList (or something) instread.

Comment: @kajacx  You should try using an `ArrayList` to construct a `JList`  before you say silly things like that.  `Vector` is neither obsolete nor deprecated.