# Attempting to add items to jList from txt File

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jlist

I have the following try catch block that executes on a button click.

```
  try {
//picking up the file I want to read in
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\users\\me\\desktop\\blah.txt"));
 String line;                                           
 try {
    //read through the file until there is nothing left and add each line to list
         while((line = in.readLine()) != null){  
            jList1.add(line, jList1);
                    }

               } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Frame2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Frame2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
```

I can successfully `System.out.println(line)` so I know something is working right. I am unable to populate the list with the lines from the text file. The above code tells me I `cannot add containers parent to self.`

Attempting to find more information has only confused me more. I have come across some places that say jLists are more complciated than this?

Comment: as your personal debuger :-) `FileReade` must be `FileReader`

Comment: Read a tutorial. This is basic stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load a TXT File into a JList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930353/how-to-load-a-txt-file-into-a-jlist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many mistakes present, too many to comment on all of them:

1) [Basic I/O](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html)

2) [Exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

3) [How to Use Lists](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

4) [Examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/CatalogJava.htm)

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String line;
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\users\\me\\desktop\\blah.txt"));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            listModel.addElement(line); //(String.valueof(line));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Frame2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }
    JList jList1 = new JList(listModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

You really cannot do it:
Read again this line: `jList1.add(line, jList1);` What did you really mean? You are adding jList1 to jList1, right? Check the code and fix it accordingly.