# File content into a jList

Tags: java, file, swing, jlist

Can anyone explain to me how can I load the content of a text file into jList ?
 I have managed to print the content of the file on the console .
 I have done a Read() function that reads the content of the file line by line and a Load() function that should display the content in the jList by calling the function Read() .

the code for load:

```
public void Load()
{

    Read();
    File archive = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        archive = new File ("Cars.txt");
        fr = new FileReader (archive);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
         Vector<String> lines = new Vector<String>();

        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            lines.add(line);
        } 
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try{
            if( null != fr ) {
                fr.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
```

the code for read:

```
public void Read()
{
    String name , type , distance, time;
    File file=new File("Cars.txt");
    FileInputStream fis=null;
    BufferedInputStream bis=null;
    DataInputStream dis=null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

        while (dis.available() != 0)
        {
            String x=dis.readLine();
            int k1=x.length();
            char []m=x.toCharArray();
            int y1=0, y2=0, z=1;
            for(int i=1;i<k1;i++)
                if(m[i]==' ' && z==1)
                {
                    y1=i;
                    z++;
                }
                else if(z==2 && m[i]==' ') {y2=i; z++; }

            k1-=y2;
            name=x.copyValueOf(x.toCharArray(), 0, y1);
            type=x.copyValueOf(x.toCharArray(), 0, y2);
            distance=x.copyValueOf(x.toCharArray(), y1+1, y2-y1-1);
            time=x.copyValueOf(x.toCharArray(), y2+1, k1-1);
            int d=Nr(distance);
            int t=Nr(time);
           // System.out.println(name + " " +q + " " + n);

            list.Add(name, type , d, t);
        }

        fis.close();
        bis.close();
        dis.close();

    }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load a TXT File into a JList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930353/how-to-load-a-txt-file-into-a-jlist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the list like:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList( model );
```

Then when you read each line of data you can use:

```
model.addElement(...);
```

Comment: It does not write anything in the jlist.

Comment: Create (and post) your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. That is create a frame with a JList (in a scrollpane) and a JButton. When you click the button, then manually add some items to the model of the JList. Once you get this working then you change the code to read a file and add each line to the model.

Comment: I have managed it somehow by using some oracle java tutorials. Thank you guys.

Comment: Although I have managed to populate the jList with the content of the file how can I read objects from that file , supposing that each line has an object? Can anyone explain how can I do that?